# Laravel: 5.6: Send email with a file using a command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send an email using a command in Laravel. I would like to send a file from a specific folder. Previously I did it using a view with a form, but now I want to send the email using a command. The file will always be in the same folder.

This is the command code:

```
<?php

namespace efsystem\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Storage;
use Mail;
use Config;

 class SendEmailEfsystem extends Command
 {
     /**
      * The name and signature of the console command.
      *
      * @var string
      */
     protected $signature = 'emails:send';

     /**
      * The console command description.
      *
      * @var string
      */
     protected $description = 'Sending emails to the users';

     /**
      * Create a new command instance.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
     }

     /**
      * Execute the console command.
      *
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function handle()
     {
         $data = array(
             'destino' => 'example@gmail.com',
             'asunto' => 'example',
         );

         Mail::send('administracion.email.email_body', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
             $message->to($data['destino']);
             $message->subject($data['asunto']);
             $message->from(Config::get('mail.username'));
         });

         $this->info('The emails are send successfully!');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you have `Commands\SendEmailEfsystem::class,` in your `Kernel.php`?

Comment: No, I have to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the "form" you used `$request['a_file']` the variable was an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` wich is an extention of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`.

what you need to do is instantiate a `File` class with the path you have.

```
$data = array(
    'destino'    => 'example@gmail.com',
    'asunto'     => 'example',
    'a_file'     => new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($pathToFile, true)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use N69S `a_file` answer

This is basic tips to help you run your command.
Your `Kernel.php` must be like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
 /**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    Commands\SendEmailEfsystem::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('emails:send')->everyMonth();
}

/**
 * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
}
```

Then if you want to run it. Simply run `php artisan emails:send`

or You want to run it using code you can use `Artisan::call('emails:send);`

Comment: Why I have to add the command to "protected"?
I want to add the command to "schedule" too.

Comment: @Kinafune look when you created a laravel project kernel.php have built in `protected commands` if you want to use schedule I already have a sample you can change `everyMonth()` with any alternative you want here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling more info